# Wrapping up Format.formattter

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to define a function `msg` which will allow printing debug messages using `Format` library with an option to control if they displayed or not via `debug` flag (set from a command line). Here is my naive first attempt:

```
let debug = ref false

let msg =
  let open Format in
  (if !debug then fprintf err_formatter else ifprintf err_formatter)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, giving me the following error message:

```
Error: The type of this expression,
       ('_a, Format.formatter, unit) format -> '_a,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the value restriction. You can solve it by "eta expansion":

```
let msg x =
    let open Format in
    if !debug then fprintf err_formatter x
    else ifprintf err_formatter x
```

Briefly stated, the value restriction avoids unsound behavior by prohibiting the generalization (treatment as fully polymorphic) of anything other than simple values. Your definition for `msg` is not a simple value. After eta expansion, the definition is a simple value (a lambda). You can read more here: [Jacques Garrigue, Relaxing the Value Restriction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf).

The new code works for me:

```
# let debug = ref true
val debug : bool ref = {contents = true}

# let msg x =
    let open Format in
    if !debug then fprintf err_formatter x
    else ifprintf err_formatter x;;
val msg : ('a, Format.formatter, unit) format -> 'a = <fun>

# let open Format in
  msg "%d " 1; msg "%s" "red rose that I mean";
  pp_print_flush err_formatter ();;
1 red rose that I mean- : unit = ()
#
```